# How do I split a string with a width of 2 into rows of a data frame as fast as possible in R

Tags: r

I have the following R script

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
string <- "just_do_its"

string_to_df <- function(string){
  vector_a <- NULL
  for(i in 1:nchar(string)){
    s <- substring(string, i, i+1)
    vector_a[i] <- s
  }
  df_a <- tibble::enframe(vector_a[1:length(vector_a) - 1], name = NULL)
  return(df_a)
}

df_string <- string_to_df(string)

df_string
```

which returns the following data frame

```
> df_string
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   value
   <chr>
 1 ju
 2 us
 3 st
 4 t_
 5 _d
 6 do
 7 o_
 8 _i
 9 it
10 ts
```

I would like to know if there are more efficient ways of splitting a string by 2 into rows of a data frame. The results should match the above output.

Also, I have heard that vectorizing code is more efficient than for-loops. If that is the case what can be done to vectorize this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`substring` is vectorized and is available in base R.

```
ind = sequence(nchar(string))
data.frame(S = substring(text = string, first = head(ind, -1), last = tail(ind, -1)))
#OR in one line
data.frame(S = substring(string, 1:(nchar(string) - 1), 2:nchar(string)))
#    S
#1  ju
#2  us
#3  st
#4  t_
#5  _d
#6  do
#7  o_
#8  _i
#9  it
#10 ts
```